# Do components defined in the router module of a feature module load in its own router-outlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular application with which I am trying to lazy load modules. Do components defined in the router module of a feature module load in its own router-outlet or do they load in the router-outlet of the parent module?

Comment: They load in their own router-outlet. This is part of the definition of lazy loading. A component and any related modules/services/directives will load independent of the parent. Only reason they will load with the parent is if they are declared in the parent module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All components regardless of how they are loaded and defined are rendered inside the parent `router-outlet` directive. Basically it doesn't matter whether the routes (router module) are loaded eagerly or lazy since the router merges all routes into one configuration.